# jQuery - On click, animate height of div with bounce effect

Tags: jquery

Im trying to build a function, that when a user clicks "show more" on my web page, the div height is doubled (if it was 300px initially, it now becomes 600px) id like this to bounce on increase though.

If clicked again id then like it to become 900 pixels, so on click the window increase 300pixels each time...

http://jsfiddle.net/dKMyg/

```
// Set height of visible window
var window = 300;

// On click increase window size
$('.show-more').click(function(){

    $('.visible-window').css({
        height : window * 2
    })

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Heres what you need:

```
// Set height of visible window
var window = 300;

// On click increase window size
$('.show-more').click(function(e){
    // Prevent the default action of the link
    e.preventDefault();

    // Animate the height, add 300px each time and easeOutBounce (for the effect)   
    $('.visible-window').animate({
        height : '+=300' // Add 300px to the current height (whatever it is)
    }, 'slow', 'easeOutBounce');

});
```

Check this JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dKMyg/2/  (Click the read more, the div height expands by 300px, and it animates as you wish)

I also added the resource jQuery Easing ([here](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js)).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.animate` instead of `.css`, and add the initial height to the current height every time.

```
// Set height of visible window
var visibleWindow = $('.visible-window');
var increase = visibleWindow.height();

// On click increase window size
$('.show-more').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    visibleWindow.animate({
        height : visibleWindow.height() + increase
    }, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dKMyg/1/

I added a `e.preventDefault()` to disable the link's default action (which was moving the page up every time); you should remove it if you don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can include [jQueryUI Effects core](http://jqueryui.com/download/) then the *bounce* easing effect will be available. See the excellent [jQueryUI easing demo page](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html) for other examples.

This example code also uses [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to change the single `height` property, which has been given a relative value `+=`. From the documentation:

> Animated properties can also be relative. If a value is supplied with a leading += or -= sequence of characters, then the target value is computed by adding or subtracting the given number from the current value of the property.

`.animate()` can also be supplied with an [*easing*](http://easings.net/) function and a duration. I have used 1500 milliseconds and the `easeOutBounce` effect.

```
// On click increase window size
$('.show-more').click(function(){
    $('.visible-window').animate({
        height: '+=100'
    }, 1500, 'easeOutBounce')
    return false // stop default click action
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rxPzZ/) (+100px increase for demo)

Answer (score 0):

// Set height of visible window

var window = 300;

// On click increase window size

$('.show-more').click(function(){

```
$('.visible-window').css({
    height :   $('.visible-window').height() + window
})
```

});